# Small files and HDFS blocks

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Does a block in Hadoop Distributed File System store multiple small files, or a block stores only 1 file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Multiple files are not stored in a single block. BTW, a single file can be stored in multiple blocks. The mapping between the file and the block-ids is persisted in the NameNode.

According to the [Hadoop : The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do)

> Unlike a filesystem for a single disk, a file in HDFS that is smaller than a single block does not occupy a full block’s worth of underlying storage.

HDFS is designed to handle large files. If there are too many small files then the NameNode might get loaded since it stores the name space for HDFS. Check this [article](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/) on how to alleviate the problem with too many small files.

Comment: Do you know how to find the mappings of blocks to files? `hadoop fsck / -files -blocks  -locations -racks` gives file to block mapping but doesn't say in which directory on the real filesystem is the block located (i.e. is it in subdirectory9 or subdirectory61).

Comment: `dfs.datanode.data.dir` property determines where on the local filesystem an DFS data node should store its blocks. If this is a comma-delimited list of directories, then data will be stored in all named directories, typically on different devices. Directories that do not exist are ignored.

Comment: No, I meant when the physical blocks are stored they could be stored in `dfs.datanode.data.dir` or in subdirectories under that directory (created by the Datanode). Is there a way to find which block is stored where (as a top-level file or inside some subdirectory)?

Answer (score 5):

Hadoop Block size is Hadoop Storage Concept. Every Time When you store a File in Hadoop it will divided into the block sizes and based on the replication factor and data locality it will be distributed over the cluster.

*For Details:*

- When you Push a File on HDFS, it will be divided into blocks. Each Block is like a individual file having a maximum size as described by the block size.
- Every block will contain a .meta file along with it, to store the metadata information of the block on Hadoop.
- If the file is very small, then the whole file will be in one block and the block (a storage file) will have same size as file and a Meta File.

*Some Commands:*

- Connect to any data Node on Your cluster [ if you have access ;)]. Then go to the storage directories for that node and you can see the actual blocks stored on the data node as below.

(Dir's are as per my cluster - /data2/dfs/dn/):

**BLOCK Size: 1 GB**

cd /data/dfs/dn -> current -> Finalized -> subDir0 -> (**here is the Gold**)

**Block used only KB of storage for small files or might be when the file size is my blocksize + some KB's**

-rw-r--r-- 1 hdfs hdfs  91K Sep 13 16:19 blk_1073781504

-rw-r--r-- 1 hdfs hdfs  19K Sep 13 16:21 blk_1073781504_40923.meta

**When the File is Bigger then the block size the block will look like something as below**

-rw-r--r-- 1 hdfs hdfs 1.0G Aug 31 12:03 blk_1073753814

-rw-r--r-- 1 hdfs hdfs 8.1M Aug 31 12:04 blk_1073753814_12994.meta

I hope it will explain the block storage stuff. If you want to know the detail how your files is stored in blocks then run

**hdfs fsck  -blocks -locations**

Let me know if I missed out anything here.

Answer (score 3):

Well you could do that using HAR (Hadoop Archive) filesystem which tries to pack multiple small files into HDFS block of special part file managed by HAR filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

A block will store a single file. If your file is bigger that BlockSize(64/128/..) then it will be partitioned in multiple blocks with respective BlockSize.

Answer (score 1):

The main point need to understand in hdfs , **`file is partioned into blocks based on size`** and not that there will be some blocks in memory, where files are stored(this is misconception)

Basically multiple files are not stored in a single block(unless it is Archive or Har file).