# How a small file is stored in HDFS

Tags: hadoop

In hadoop definitive guide :

**a 1 MB file stored with a block size of 128 MB uses 1 MB of disk space, not128 MB**.

what does this mean ? 
does it use 1MB of size in a block of 128MB or 1MB is used  and reamining 127MB is free to occupy by some other file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is often a misconception about HDFS - the block size is more about how a single file is split up / partitioned, not about some reserved part of the file system.

Behind the schemes, each block is stored on the DataNodes underlying files system as a plain file (and an associated checksum). If you look into the data node folder on your disks you should be able to find the file (if you know the file's block ID and data node allocations - which you can discover from the NameNode Web UI).

So back to your question, a 1MB file with a block size of 16MB/32MB/128MB/512MB/1G/2G (you get the idea) will still only be a 1MB file on the data nodes disk. The difference between the block size and the amount of data stored in that block is then free for the underlying file system to use as it sees fit (by HDFS, or something else).

Comment: i'm totaly confused "block is then free for the underlying file system to use " what does this mean. suppose a block size is fixed as 128MB and it is occupied by 1MB file .do u mean to say the remaining 127MB is free and this 127MB free space is free to occupy by some other file ??

Comment: Exactly right - Hadoop does not 'reserve' 128MB (or whatever the block size is) on the underlying file system, it will create a file 1MB in size (i.e. only use what it actually needs).

Comment: if it stores 1Mb file as 1Mb file then why the concept of block size, come into picture in hadoop??

Comment: Because a 1GB file will be stored in blocks of 128MB (for example), with each block being replicated on 3 (typically) nodes in the cluster. The idea being that it's quicker for 8 tasks to process 128MB each, rather than a single task processing all 1G.

Comment: This question is a bit old, but does that mean it's not inefficient to store small files on HDFS? I was worried that each 1MB file would waste entire 128MB blocks, leaving the remaining 127MB unusable to HDFS.

Comment: yes it's not efficient, cause the namenode will need lot of memory in order to keep track of all files and also because hadoop will create as much mapper jobs as blocks to read.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop Block size is Hadoop Storage Concept. Every Time When you store a File in Hadoop it will divided into the block sizes and based on the replication factor and data locality it will be distributed over the cluster.

**For Details you can find my answer here**

[Small files and HDFS blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562934/small-files-and-hdfs-blocks/46242588#46242588)