# Blocks and Mappers based on file size

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Let's say I have 3 files that I want to store in HDFS and want to read them via MapReduce.

So,there are 3 files inside a HDFS location `/omega/usecase/input` as file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt

Size of these 3 files are `file1.txt(64MB),file2.txt(32MB),file3.txt(1MB)`

Also lets assume that the default block size is **64MB** and replication factor is 3

I would like to know how many blocks  will be there  for these 3 files and How many mappers will be executed if I write a MapReduce program that will read the input dir `/omega/usecase/input`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Small files and HDFS blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562934/small-files-and-hdfs-blocks)

Comment: So the answer should be 3 Mappers? is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be 3 blocks in HDFS (one per each file).

Each of these blocks will be replicated to three different machines. So they will approximately occupy 3 times the size of all files = `3 * (64 + 32 + 1) MB`.

When you execute M/R job, there will be 3 mappers by default (one per each block).

Answer (score 0):

3 blocks one each file (block is just a logical separation).

And three mapper process one per block.

Comment: Right.. Got it now,Thanks Sir