# what happens to HDFS block size in case of smaller file size

Tags: hdfs

i read but still confused
what happens if a file size is less than block size.

if file size is 1MB will it consume 64MB or only 1MB

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562934/small-files-and-hdfs-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will consume only 1 MB. That remaining can be used to store some other files block. 
**Ex:** Consider your HDFS Data node total size is 128MB and block size is 64MB.
    Then HDFS can store 2, 64MB blocks
    or 128, 1MB blocks
    or any number of block that can consume 128MB of Data node.